# Adding local files to source control

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I added some files on my local machine last night and I thought that I am going to see the option of adding then to the source safe but I am not seeing that option at all.

I am attaching the screenshot for your reference.

[image: Source control problem]

Comment: Adding local files to source control is the point of having it.  Your red arrow doesn't otherwise provide great insight into your problem.

Comment: As you can see, If I add a new file into the project while working, then it should be added to the source control directly( atleast that is what I expect). But here I don't see it being under Source control because I don't see a lock on the icon and Check-in option when I right-click that....

Answer (score 0):

The source control provider needs to know that there is a file to be added to source control. It gets this information from Visual Studio. However, there are some files which are not (automatically) added to source control. Besides files not in the solution, this also happens with files which are in a different directory or subdirectory than the project.

To clarify this, if your project is in Projects/MySolution/MyProject and you add a file to that project, where the file is stored in Projects/MySolution/MyLibraries, then that file logically belongs to someone else and VS does not add it to source control in MyProject. Perhaps this is the case?

Comment: Well, i just found out this but it still needs not explanation. For some reason, these files are not under source control by default and I have to explicitly add them.

Comment: BUT when I go to Source controler, I see an option called "Add items to source control" and when I do that, it shows me list of all  the remaining items which are like these "orphaned" items and I can actually add them to source control. BUT the question here is that Why was it NOT added into the source control when I first created that file under the same project.

Comment: Perhaps your source control provider doesn't automatically add them. I use AnkhSVN; there it works fine with the caveats noted above.

Comment: Source control provider? Well, I have not set up TFS here,my Admin has.

Comment: But I think if  my all the source control activities are managed by TFS engine, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, by being a source control provider. Look under Tools, Options, Source Control. Then check the settings there.